# uniform continuity of quotient of two uniform continuous functions

Tags: uniform-continuity

as we know quotient $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ of two real valued continuous functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ defined on $\mathbb R$ and so that $g(x) \neq 0\ \forall x \in \mathbb R $ is continuous. What can we say about the quotient of two uniformly continuous functions?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the function $f(x)=\exp(-|x|)$ is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$, but $1/f(x)=\exp(|x|)$ is not.

Comment: thanks if there are some extra conditions by the help of which quotient of two uniformly continuous functions be uniformly continuous. and please elobrate a little how e^|-x| is uniformly continuous but e^|x| is not.i want prepare for a paper national eligibility test. would you like to prefer me a book linear algebra and for real analysis.i sall be very thankful to you for this

Comment: It seems that if $f$ and $g$ are uniformly continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ and there exists a number $c>0$ such that $g(x)\ge c$ for any $x\in\mathbb R$ then the quotient function $f/g$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: It seems that you can prove the uniform continuity of the first function and uniform discontinuity of the second using Lagrange theorem. For instance, if $y>x>0$ then there exists a number $\theta\in[x,y]$ such that $\frac {\exp (-y)-\exp (-x)}{y-x}=-\exp (-\theta)$, so $|\exp (-y)-\exp (-x)|=|\exp (-\theta)|| y-x |\le | y-x |$. Similarly, there exists a number $\varphi\in[x,y]$ such that $\frac {\exp (y)-\exp (x)}{y-x}=\exp (\varphi)$, so $|\exp (y)-\exp (x)|=|\exp (\varphi)|| y-x |\ge$ $\exp(x)| y-x |$.

Comment: Unfortunately, all good books on linear algebra and analysis which I know and which I used to study are in Russian or in Ukrainian, so you’ll better ask another person for such books in English.

Answer (score 0):

No:
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{t^2}{1+t^4}}{\dfrac{1}{1+t^4}}.$$